# chess board (box spacing) with css

Tags: spacing, box

**I'm trying to make like the picture but I cant figure out how to make spaces between the boxes and how to make inside square?**[here is what I'm trying to acheave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuMp9.png)

html not full

```
      <table>
          <div>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
          </div>
          <div>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
          </div>
          <div>

CSS 

    th {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      padding: 15px;
    }
    
    th:nth-child(even) {
      border: 5px solid rgb(89, 218, 89);
      background: orangered;
    }
    th:nth-child(odd) {
      border: 5px solid orangered;
      background: rgb(89, 218, 89);
    }
```